# How to create database using Database Project in Visual Studio if doesn't exists?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I have a Database project for my personal project and I am trying to deploy my code to my DEV server. I frequently delete and re-create my DEV Server. Right now, DEV Server is newly created with SQL Server. Every time I want to deploy my code I have to manually create Database Project and then publish database project. I want to automate creation of Database with database project deployment.

Right now, I have a script that creates database, but I have to execute it manually. And this is working perfectly but I want to automate this step as well.

Is this even possible? If yes, then how? Please explain step by step. Also what will we mention for Initial Catalog in connection string?

Edit:
I tried to create Database by using

```
CREATE DATABASE LocalDbTest
```

in Pre-Deployment Script. But it didn't work. It is creating Database, but then tables are not getting created tables under it. Since I used master database as default database, it is creating table under master. It is not letting me select `LocalDbTest` database as default because it is not yet created, so I have to select Master as my default database. I tried to Change Database by:

```
USE LocalDbTest
GO
```

I used it just after creating Database but this didn't work because when generating script it is changing back to default database. This part is coming automatically when generating script.

```
USE [$(DatabaseName)];
GO
```

Also Visual Studio is not letting me add database name in front of table name like:

```
CREATE TABLE [LocalDbTest].[dbo].[TestTable]
```

I am getting error:

```
When you create an object of this type in a database project, the object's name must contain no more than two parts.
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: VS 2017 and 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a script ready for database creation, you can use the Pre-build event to call SQLCMD and run your script.

Edit:
If you have trouble pointing to a database that does not exist, you may have to manually edit the publish profile (ex. `dev.publish.xml`) and set the `TargetDatabaseName` element explicitly. You can also set `CreateNewDatabase` element to `True` if you want to be recreated every time it gets published.

Answer:
You can use a publish profile and hardcode the target database in it.

Comment: @Devang Do you specify the database `LocalDbTest`  in your deployment connection string?

Comment: I have edited my question and added more information. I was not able to specify the database LocalDbTest in your deployment connection string because it is not yet created so it was not letting me select it.

Comment: @Devang You have two options. You can use a publish profile and hardcode the target database in it. Or, you can create an empty database in the server and modify your script to do a drop(if exists)/create on the database.